# 404 Not Found, but route exist in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I am trying to hit on name and get the details of lead but every time it shows 404 not found

blade file code

```xml
@foreach($lead as $lead)
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="{{ url('show_lead', $lead->id) }}">{{ $lead->first_name }} {{ $lead- >last_name }}</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ $lead->company }}</td>
    <td>{{ $lead->email }}</td>
    <td>{{ $lead->phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ $lead->lead_source }}</td>
    <td>{{ $lead->lead_status }}</td>
    <td>
      <a class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit" href="{{ url('edit_lead', $lead->id) }}"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger fas fa-trash-alt" onclick="return confirm('Sure You Want To Delete This Lead')" href="{{ url('/delete_lead', $lead->id) }}"></a>    
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

route:

```php
Route::get('show_lead/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'show_lead']);
```

controller

```php
public function show_lead()
{
    $lead = lead::find($id);

    return view('admin.leads.show_lead', compact('lead'));
}
```

Comment: What is the resulting URL _after_ you click the name? Give your route a name and use `{{ route() }}` instead of `{{ url() }}`.

Comment: fyi, your method doesn't take any parameter

Comment: thanks to all of you i fixed the error

Answer (score 3):

You should give a name to your route.

```php
Route::get('show_lead/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'show_lead'])->name('show_lead');
```

Then, in your blade file, call this route using the `route($name, $parameters = [])` helper.

```xml
<a href="{{ route('show_lead', ['id' => $lead->id]) }}"></a>
```

And in your controller, you need to add the `{id}` parameter you've defined to the controller method's arguments.

```php
public function show_lead($id)
{
    $lead = lead::find($id);

    return view('admin.leads.show_lead', compact('lead'));
}
```

Lastly, in case you've been caching your routes in development for some reason, run `php artisan route:clear`.

---

Using route model binding, you could do this with less lines

```php
Route::get('show_lead/{lead}', [HomeController::class, 'show_lead'])->name('show_lead');
```

```xml
<a href="{{ route('show_lead', [$lead]) }}"></a>
```

```php
public function show_lead(Lead $lead)
{
    return view('admin.leads.show_lead', compact('lead'));
}
```